Managing JDBC Connections using Java Virtual Threads
We have a service in Java 17 which executes logic on our end sends request to a third party system. The response time from the third party system is around 800-1400ms.
We have a ThreadPoolExecutor for this with a size of 12 (cannot further increase it due to infrastructure limitations)
Our request sending rate was 5-8 requests/S due to the response time of the 3rd party system. To increase throughput we are upgrading to Java 21 to use Virtual Threads. However, during development testing there seems to be another issue being faced.
Our request sending rate has increased to around 50 requests/s. But we are facing Exceptions related to JDBC connection request failure. My db connection pool size must be around 100.
When my service starts there are 10 connections belonging to my microservice.
When sending requests using ThreadPoolExecutor: 13 additional connections so total 23.
When using newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor: total of 94 connections
I use the following query to monitor my PostGre Database V13.9
SELECT pid, datname, usename, application_name, client_addr, client_port, backend_start, query_start, state_change, query, state
FROM pg_stat_activity where application_name ='PostgreSQL JDBC Driver';

Exceptions:
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:466) ~[spring-orm-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:531) ~[spring-tx-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:405) ~[spring-tx-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:610) ~[spring-tx-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPerTaskExecutor$TaskRunner.run(ThreadPerTaskExecutor.java:314) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.run(VirtualThread.java:309) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection [FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections] [n/a]

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPerTaskExecutor$TaskRunner.run(ThreadPerTaskExecutor.java:314) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.run(VirtualThread.java:309) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection [FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections] [n/a]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]

What I understand is when using ThreadPoolExecutor of 12 threads, each thread makes an connection and uses that. When using Virtual Threads, as soon as any Virtual Thread gets busy in response waiting, or Thread.sleep, another Virtual Thread takes lead. As soon as I initiate a load test, I notice a burst of connections, some resulting in exceptions (For example 11 requests failed out of 1500 (due to JDBC error)), and then the process going forward moves smoothly utilising the max 94 connections currently that I have.
Question is, how do I resolve this, and limit the number of processes initiated at a time. And more importantly, limit the number of connections/resuse connections created to the database. I have multiple other applications to the database, so will not be able to increase them much.
I have tried using System property "jdk.virtualThreadScheduler.maxPoolSize" by passing the VM Arugment -Djdk.virtualThreadScheduler.maxPoolSize=5
But the exception still occurs even if set -Djdk.virtualThreadScheduler.maxPoolSize=1
What am I missing? Is it that Virtual Threads should be used for basic I/O tasks, CPU tasks, rather than communications with Third Party Systems?
Some code of how my Virtual Threads are initiated:
this.executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
this.taskExecutorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor();

this.executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 0L, this.pollingTime.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); //Called once when service starts

public void run() {
    this.taskExecutorService.execute(//my runnable job);
}

I also tried using counters/semaphores to restrict Virtual Threads. It reduces throughput but it still creates new connections more compared to the ThreadPoolExecutor. Is it designed this way? I suspect each virtual thread / process creates a new connection, whereas in ThreadPoolExecutor it utilises the connection allocated to its PID. Any  clarification or suggestions please?
Edit: (JDBC Connection Code)
I see most delete queries in open connections, as that is what is executed when sending requests via virtual threads. Following is the code.
public Optional<Job> getNextJob(String queue) {
    Optional<Job> job = Optional.empty();

    try {
        Connection connection = this.dataSource.getConnection();

        try {
            String sql = "DELETE FROM scheduler_task WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM scheduler_task WHERE queue = ? and trigger_date < now() LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED) RETURNING id, queue, reference_id, trigger_date";
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            try {
                ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();

                try {
                    if (resultSet.next()) {
                        job = Optional.of(this.mapToJob(resultSet));
                    }
                } catch (Throwable var14) {
                    if (resultSet != null) {
                        try {
                            resultSet.close();
                        } catch (Throwable var13) {
                            var14.addSuppressed(var13);
                        }
                    }
                    throw var14;
                }

                if (resultSet != null) {
                    resultSet.close();
                }
            } catch (Throwable var15) {
                if (stmt != null) {
                    try {
                        stmt.close();
                    } catch (Throwable var12) {
                        var15.addSuppressed(var12);
                    }
                }

                throw var15;
            }
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
        } catch (Throwable var16) {
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (Throwable var11) {
                    var16.addSuppressed(var11);
                }
            }

            throw var16;
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }

        return job;
    } catch (SQLException var17) {
        log.error("error", var17);
        throw new Exception(var17);
    }
}


Not sure what you asking. Do you want to throttle the number of tasks performing database work? If so, use Semaphore with a number of permits configured to your desired maximum simultaneous database tasks.

You're not going to get any useful responses until you exhibit some code that creates JDBC connections and releases them.

@BasilBourque I used semaphores to control the number of virtual threads at a time. E.g 20 or 50. But still it creates more connections than the allowed virtual threads e.g 70,80,90. This doesnot happen with the normal Thread Pool. Is it that once the connection is opened by a virtual thread, it closes after all I/O is done, meanwhile other virtual threads incoming open new connections...

@user207421 added JDBC code

By the way, use try-with-resources syntax to automatically close your JDBC resources: Connection, PreparedStatement, ResultSet.

See documentation. And see my Answer.

@BasilBourque To be honest, the code in the question looks like decompiled bytecode, where the original source used try-with-resources.

That is correct, the original code has try-with-resources syntax. I did not place that as there would be debate that does it close the connections, because it explicitly doesn't show any connection closing. I assume the problem is Virtual Threads need to be limited. If in any case my virtual threads increase to 200 at a time, and i have 100 connections to DB, then they will face exceptions right? Whats the most efficient way to limit virtual threads?

Are you using Hikari to access the database? It comes by default with Spring Boot Data. If so, there's an issue with it https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/2151

Apart from the technical issues with proliferated connections, I don't quite understand what you wanted to achieve switching to restricted amount of virtual threads in your case of response around 800-1400ms. There might be some benefit switching from platform threads to limited amount of virtual threads using semaphores and the kind, but it is hardly applicable to your case of such slow responses. What benefit could you get from that switching? Save few CPU cycles on faster context switching for virtual threads than for platform one?

What Im aiming at is if the response is delayed, rather than 10 platforms threads working around in the pool every 0.8-1.4 secs, use Virtual Threads to initiate new requests and doesn't matter when the response comes. So if I have 10,000 requests, they can be executed (without response) in less time e.g 2 mins, rather than sending+getting response and executing all requests in e.g 20 mins.. So i guess i just want to maximise my db connections utility. E.g i cannot afford to block more than 12 threads, but i can afford to use all 90 of my db connections

I believe the issue is with the uncountable Virtual Threads initiated which each want to create new connections. What would have been best would be that if I have 90 available db connections, I limit platform threads in use to 90 using jdk.virtualThreadScheduler.maxPoolSize. This pool size of 90 platform threads create 90 connections. Then initiate a lot of virtual threads, which don't each create new DB connections, rather reuse those 90 platform thread's connections.
As suggested by Basil Bourque I have limited my request sending via Virtual Threads using Semaphore.
private void executeJob(Job job) {
     semaphore.acquire();
     jobExecutor.execute(job);
     semaphore.release();
}

and to avoid blocking calls waiting on acquire, only execute above method if:
if (semaphore.availablePermits() > 0) {
    Job = //find job
    executeJob(job);
}

This seems to work, and limit my connections in the database. Also, the throughput has increased from 8 requests/s to 70 requests/s despite the slow responses.
Edit:
As mentioned by @igor.zh and during testing available permits is an estimated value only, I have modified my  method as follows. Also I was using tomcat-jdbc pool, and have switched to Hikari which seems to be more efficient with the connections.
private void executeJob(Job job) {
    if (!semaphore.tryAcquire()) {
        //let the thread die
        return;
    }
    try {
        jobExecutor.execute(job);
    } finally {
        semaphore.release();
    }
}


Do not use Semaphore.availablePermits for synchronization purposes! The Javadoc of this method says: This method is typically used for debugging and testing purposes. Your last snippet is not atomic: e.g. right after non-zero permit count is returned, one or more other threads might jump in, and the count could be 0. Your first snippet is kind of OK (except that it is still better to do release in the finally block of try-finally statement). I think blocking is what exactly you need (especially when you use virtual threads - it will just release the Carrier).

Are you using Hikari to access the database? It comes by default with Spring Boot Data. If so, there's an issue with it
https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/2151
What happens, basically, is that once created, the connection stays in the ThreadLocal storage. When using a thread pool, the first time a thread accesses the database, it creates a connection and stores it in the ThreadLocal space of its thread. If this thread is reused, as is the case of a Thread Pool, the connection is already there and it's reused. However, when working with virtual threads, threads are created and destroyed continuously, so their ThreadLocal space is cleared and so, connections are created and destroyed once per task. In your case, if you have 1000 threads trying to access the database, they may try to create 1000 connections.

Thanks. It does seem to be the same issue. But how can I be sure if my project uses Hikari? Im using JDK 21, Spring Boot 3.2.1. com.querydsl querydsl-apt 5.0.0 jakarta , javax.sql.DataSource. As far as I know and the logs show hibernate

Shouldn't implementations of Virtual Threads be like: they execute, but the connections are created by platform threads. So when a Virtual Thread be assigned to a platform thread, it will reuse the platform thread's connection. Something like that. Rather than Virtual Threads creating new connections.

What might be the case is, that it does happens this way (i.e Platform Threads create new connections, not virtual threads). But if for e.g there are 256 total Platform threads, then we cannot be sure if we set platform threads to limit to 90, then only 90 same platform threads will be assigned with your virtual threads. Rather any of the 90 of 256 platform threads will be used, resulting in unique connections. Just some thoughts.

We are using Tomcat JDBC

@Shoaib Just looking at the logs you should see some of them from hikari packages. Also, if it's in the classpath (looking at the maven dependency tree) most likely it's being used, as it's configured by default by Spring Boot.

Also, it doesn't work like this. Virtual threads use a handful of real OS threads (usually as much as cores) but the concept of ThreadLocal is something associated to Java threads, not OS threads. Each Java thread has its own ThreadLocal space. In traditional threads, as a Java thread is an OS thread, and threads are reused, the ThreadLocal space survives from one task to another. In virtual threads, each task is executed in a new Java thread, which has its own new ThreadLocal space and they are mounted over OS threads but, since the ThreadLocal is something associated to Java, it's lost.

Actually I have come to conclusion that this is exactly what my issue is. I have 100 connections. When I use newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor , there is no limit to the virtual threads and they initiate tasks, which result in connections. When they exceed I get the pool errors. If I use semaphores and allow only 50, or 80 at a time, there are no exceptions. So will this resolve in the referred hikari issue by resuing connections in the case of virtual threads? Or this is a natural issue and we are bound to use semaphores?

Using a semaphore will prevent you from creating an unlimited number of connections, so your application will not fail but it will create a connection per task, so the performance will be worse than using a traditional thread pool. In the traditional one, it will create one connection per thread and and, at one point, every task will reuse this connections. With virtual threads, each task will create its own connection, which takes time and hinders the performance.
